# node-nanomsg - subscriber does not receive messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, nanomsg

I have two `.js` files - `pub.js` for publication and `sub.js` for subscription. These files are actually a 'split' version of the example shown on [node-nanomsg GitHub site](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-nanomsg#check-it-out). The `pub.js` writes to `tcp://127.0.0.1:7789` and `sub.js` reads from the same. I start the `sub.js` first followed by `pub.js`. While the `pub.js` completes quickly, the `sub.js` never receives the message.

### `pub.js`

```
var nano = require('nanomsg')
var pub = nano.socket('pub')
pub.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:7789')
//
pub.send('Hello')
pub.close()
```

### `sub.js`

```
var nano = require('nanomsg')
var sub = nano.socket('sub')
sub.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:7789')
//
sub.on('data', function(buf) {
    console.log(String(buf))
    sub.close()
})
```

## UPDATE

If `pub.js` is written as below and `sub.js` started first, then the communication goes through.

```
var nano = require('nanomsg')
var pub = nano.socket('pub')
pub.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:7789')
//
setTimeout(() => {
    pub.send('Hello')
},2000)
//pub.close()
```

But, a pub-sub paradigm does not require the publishers and subscribers to be aware of each other. How do I enable a pub-sub system with `nanomsg`?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. Are you sure you didn't start `pub.js` first in your original example? The only difference between the original code and the Update is that you add a timeout to `pub.js`. What if you just wait 2 seconds in your original example and then start `pub.js`

Comment: Well that's the question. It seems to work with a timeout only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the communication is closed by the publisher before binding the tcp socket completes.

The library doesn't provide async versions of `bind` and `connect`, and it seems like `bind` doesn't completely finish executing when the function returns. Adding a timeout is just a workaround for this problem.

See this discussion on their Github repository: [rewrite bind/connect and remove setTimeouts from tests](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-nanomsg/pull/114)
Unfortunately the pull request got closed and the async feature is still not implemented.

If you look at the [examples](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-nanomsg/tree/master/examples) they provide, they all rely on timeouts, which means the problem is acknowledged by the developers. In my opinion this library is not ready for production use, because of this reliance on timeouts.

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation. I think, this issue exists with [Ømq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:_start) also.

Comment: Not sure, I see that 0mq provides both `bind` and `bindSync`: https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/blob/master/lib/index.js#L435